# my app have a problem after i refresh the page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

when i open my app for the first time it work just fine but when i refresh the page it give me a url to my index.html file ( /client/build/index.html ) , i have deploy it on heroku

that is the code in my app.js file that create the server

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

// create a server for socket io

    const http = require('http');
    const socketio = require('socket.io');
    const server = http.createServer(app);
    module.exports = io = socketio(server);

    // my middle ware
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    // Init Middelware
    app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

    // my router
    const postRoute = require('./nodeapi/routers/post');
    const authRouter = require('./nodeapi/routers/auth');
    const usersRouter = require('./nodeapi/routers/users');
    const friendRouter = require('./nodeapi/routers/friend');
    const chatRouter = require('./nodeapi/routers/chats');
    const mongoDB = require('./nodeapi/mongodb-database/db');
    const port = process.env.PORT;

    // Connect monogo database
    mongoDB();

    // Middel ware
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    // Get the routes
    app.use('/', postRoute);
    app.use('/', authRouter);
    app.use('/', usersRouter);
    app.use('/', friendRouter);
    app.use('/', chatRouter);
    app.use('/file/', express.static('./uploads/'));

    // connect to socket io
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {});
    //Serve static assets in productio
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      // Set static folder
      app.use(express.static('./client/build'));
      app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.send(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
      });
    }
    // listen to the port
    server.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`this is port ${port}`);
    });
```

this is when i open it for the first time 
[image]

this is when i refresh the page
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You just need to send it as file not a text

```
app.use(express.static('./client/build'));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Comment: i did the solution you said above it give me this erro (Internal Server Error)  @Ahmed Hamed

Comment: @mohamednageh Yes my bad, I edit the code. hope it works now.

Comment: i tried this but it give me not found after refresh the page

Comment: @mohamednageh would you please post the project file structure?

Comment: it worked i edit the index.html file direction , i will be like this 
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
thanks alot Ahmed

Comment: do you previous experience with socket.io Ahmed ?